# Is there a way to have a "Line Break" between divs?

Tags: html, css

So I have a menu, 4 menu points and I want to put them in a square 2x2. Is there a way to do that WITHOUT having a class for the first two and one for the other ones?

Thanks for any help :)

UPDATE:
I did mess around a little more and I'm using the flex box structure, I'm sorry for not posting this information:

```
  ul {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  }

  ul li {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    height: 44%;
    margin: 3%;
  }
```

Comment: Give the children a width of `50%` of parent and `float: left`

Comment: doesn't work with the flex box thingy for some reason (updated the post) :|

Comment: Judging from the code added, you want this to work on WebKit browsers only?

Comment: not necessarily, this is just what I got right now since I'll be making the site for webkit first, then try to make style sheets for theh other ones / expand on the current one so that it works for all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  For one, you can use floating and set the widths accordingly.  See the example below, or http://jsfiddle.net/BUPX7/ for a live example.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    width: 200px;
}

ul li {
    width: 100px;   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;   
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, thanks, but I can't get it to work with the flexbox layout I'm using (updated the post, sorry for the missing information)

Answer (score 1):

There is a line break between `div` elements by default. You are apparently using some CSS to override that. You need to modify the CSS code accordingly, or select a different approach.

The simplest way, assuming ”menu points” are links, is to use

```
<div><a ...>link1</a> <a ...>link2</a></div>
<div><a ...>link3</a> <a ...>link4</a></div>
```

But if you are using some elaborated markup and wish to create the break in CSS alone, then you may need some elaborated selectors like `:nth-child(3)`.

Comment: I updated the post with some more information, how would you do it in this specific case? I really only have one class for ul and one for il, so I can't "group them up". I tried messing with the :nth-child selector, but I couldn't get it to work.