# How to ensure there is never space in between div's?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have a very unique problem which occurs only when font sizes dip below a certain level. Here is the code that I am working with which gives an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                width: 18px;
                height: 18px;
                background-color: black;
                border: 1px solid blue;

                clear: both;
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: top;
                color: red;
                text-align: center;

                font-size: 10px;

                line-height: 18px;
            }
        </style>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div>#</div><div>@</div><div>A</div><div>B</div><div>I</div><div>#</div><div>#</div><br><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

This yields exactly what I want it to - side by side divs with a single character inside each. If I try to scale this down, however, to a div size of 12x12 a gap appears in between each of the rows which I cannot afford to have. What tricks can I apply to get my desired output?

Here is what I mean by "scaling it down":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                width: 12px; /* change made here */
                height: 12px; /* change made here */
                background-color: black;
                border: 1px solid blue;

                clear: both;
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: top;
                color: red;
                text-align: center;

                font-size: 10px;

                line-height: 12px; /* change made here */
            }
        </style>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div>#</div><div>@</div><div>A</div><div>B</div><div>I</div><div>#</div><div>#</div><br><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up the following that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/gfbxrgum/

1. Wrap the rows in an element that will break. I just created a block level span that will clear both.
2. Float the divs and set clear to none.

CSS

```
div {
    width: 12px; /* change made here */
    height: 12px; /* change made here */
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid blue;

    clear: none;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;

    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 12px; /* change made here */
}
span {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML

```
<span><div>#</div><div>@</div><div>A</div><div>B</div><div>I</div><div>#</div><div>#</div></span><span><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></span>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the working solution. I'm not much of a web developer so there was no way I was ever going to figure this one out. You've been a tremendous help to me and I'll be sure to credit you in my source code. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your Style. You have a 'br' tag in between your Divs. Remove it and it'll work like a charm. :-D

If you still need to have a line break please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546227/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-line-break-between-divs) thread in SO